# Is the language $L=\{ww^f|w\in \{0,1\}^*\}$ CFL?

Tags: computability, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Where $w^f=$flipping the bits of w.

For example, $(0010)^f=1101$, $(010111)^f=101000$

I tried to prove that $L$ is not CFL using the pumping lemma, with no succeed.

In addition, I need to prove that $\overset{-}{L}$ is CFL (and to find a CFG),
But it seems that both of $L$ and 
 $\overset{-}{L}$ are the same.

Comment: Hint: This is basically the same as the language of all valid nestings of brackets (over the alphabet $[$,$]$,$($,$)$). Do you think that language is context-free? Hint: Lots of programming languages have context-free grammars (if you exclude rules like variables have to be defined before they are used, and typing rules). For $\bar L$ - what's that supposed to be? The complement, i.e. $w \in L$ exactly if $w \notin \bar L$?

Comment: @Eyalbason Doesn't pumping lemma work if you try to pump the word $0^n1^n0^n1^n0^n1^n \in L$, where $n$ is much larger than the pumping length?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, $0^n1^n0^n1^n0^n1^n$ is working for the pumping lemma, as Dan Shved said.

For the second question, what is $\bar L$ ? any word that does not belong to $L$. So either :

1. a word of odd length
2. a word $w.\alpha.x.\beta.z$ with any words $x,y,z$ such that $|w|+|z|=|x|$ and two identical letters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. As $\alpha=\beta$, when you cut your word in two halves, they won't be the flipped of each other.

So you can build a grammar as

- $S\rightarrow E|F$ ($E$ for even, $F$ for odd (to avoid confusion between $0$ and $O$)
- $L\rightarrow 0\;|\;1$ ($L$ is any letter)
- $F\rightarrow L\;|\;LFL$
- $E\rightarrow E_0E_0\;|\;E_1E_1$
- $E_0\rightarrow 0\;|\;LE_0L$
- $E_1\rightarrow 1\;|\;LE_1L$

As you have a grammar for $\bar L$, it is a CFL.

Comment: About the first part, what happens if the pumping part sits exactly in the middle of the string? Then pumping it will still result in a word in the language

Comment: @Roy, no because you will obtain $1^n0^n1^{n+k}0^{n+k}1^n0^n$ but in the language it has to be $1^n0^n1^{n+k}0^n1^n0^{n+k}$

Comment: Thanks, I had symetry in mind for some reason...